# Dynamic Linq Query where

Tags: c#, linq

I have a combobox and a Textbox. I can select a column in the combobox and then search for the thing.

So if I select "country" and type in the Textbox "Netherlands" (or a part of it) It should bring up all the customers that live in The Netherlands.

However, this does not work.

I have the country now hardcoded but how do I made that dynamic, so it's what I selected in the combobox?

This is my code:

```
CustomerContext context = new CustomerContext();

IQueryable<customer> customers = from x in context.customers
                                 where x.country.Contains(SearchBox.Text)
                                 select x;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Brute force/straightforward:**

```
IQueryable<customer> customers = from x in context.customers
                                 where (ComboBox.SelectedValue == "Country") && x.country.Contains(SearchBox.Text)
                                 ||    (ComboBox.SelectedValue == "City") && x.city.Contains(SearchBox.City)
                                 ||    (ComboBox.SelectedValue == "State") && x.state.Contains(SearchBox.State)
                                 select x;
```

There is absolutely nothing wrong with the above solution, but a lot of engineers will pooh pooh it because it doesn't seem maintainable or elegant or whatever. Harumph.

**Fancy/elegant (a.k.a. complicated):**

Note: You must arrange the items in the ComboBox in an order that matches the `searches` array.

```
static private readonly Func<customer, string>[] _searches;

static private Class() //Static constructor
{
    _searches = new Func<customer,string>[]
    {
        (c) => customer.City,
        (c) => customer.State,
        (c) => customer.Country 
    }
}

protected virtual void DoSearch() //Handles the search event
{
    var search = _searches[ComboBox.SelectedIndex];

    IQueryable<customer> customers = from x in context.customers
                                     where search(x).Contains(SearchBox.Text)
                                     select x;
}
```

The idea here is that you set up a series of lambdas in an array. Each lambda accepts a customer as input and returns one of the properties.

When the user triggers a search, you use the ordinal position in the combo box to choose a lambda expression corresponding to the property to be searched. You then use the lambda expression in your LINQ, causing the WHERE expression to search the property chosen by the lambda.

**Using a dictionary**

If you don't like the dependency between the array and the ordering of the combo box, you can use a dictionary instead:

```
static private readonly Dictionary<string, Func<customer, string>> _searches;

static private Class() //Static constructor
{
    _searches = new Dictionary<string, Func<customer,string>>();
    _searches.Add("City",    (c) => customer.City);
    _searches.Add("State",   (c) => customer.State);
    _searches.Add("Country", (c) => customer.Country);
}

protected virtual void DoSearch() //Handles the search event
{
    var search = _searches[ComboBox.SelectedValue];

    IQueryable<customer> customers = from x in context.customers
                                     where search(x).Contains(SearchBox.Text)
                                     select x;
}
```

Comment: How does that `static private Class()` work? I cannot get it to work. It always gives me the error "Method must have a return type"

Comment: And an other thing. When I just put the code in my method `DoSearch()` it asks for an object reference. When I do that the code breaks and when I make the `get set` static the code breaks aswell.

Comment: It's the constructor.  You need to substitute the name of your class for `Class()`.

Comment: Okay, yeah, that worked. thanks. Now the other problem: on the `customer.country` or any of them I get the following error: `An object reference is required for the non-static field` making the field static solves the error but brakes the code. How do I solve that?